# Workaround for MySQL limited TIMESTAMP range?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Does anyone know of a workaround for storing values outside of the range '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-09 03:14:07' UTC in a MySQL TIMESTAMP field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you alter the column to use the DATETIME type, you can store a wider range of values.

the TIMESTAMP type's range is '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-09 03:14:07' UTC.

the DATETIME type's range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Comment: My reason in using TIMESTAMP is that it automatically converts the date value based on the database connection's timezone setting.

Comment: You HERO! It was a mystery for quite some days, but this was for me the reason birth dates of people before 1970 where all zero values. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMP shouldn't be used for literal date/time values, it is for SQL Server synchronization.

Use SMALLDATETIME or DATETIME.

Comment: Plus, it automatically converts the date to the timezone set for the connection. Pushing this conversion to the database level, out of the code level, makes a LOT of sense and prevents a LOT of potential bugs.