# MySQL TIMESTAMP Update Warning

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-timestamp

MySQL is giving me a hard time to update a timestamp column

```
mysql> describe payments;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| cat_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| amount  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| time    | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to set the time of record 1 to Jan 1st 2040

```
mysql> select * from payments;
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | cat_id | amount | time                |
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |      4 |     40 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  2 |       1 |      3 |     30 | 2030-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But it gives me an out of range warning

```
mysql> update payments set time='2040-01-01 00:00:00' where id=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'time' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002665/workaround-for-mysql-limited-timestamp-range) may interest you.

Comment: Ouch, I didn't see that comming. Changing the structure is a bit intrusive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the datatype of your column from `Timestamp` to `Datetime` as for the [limitation of Timestamp to take the maximum data as '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

Comment: The time was indeed out of range. It must be <= 2038

Comment: @MonoThreaded:- Yes that was the issue! And as I mentioned in answer you need to change the datatype!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer you're looking for:

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

The date you're trying to set is to high.

Comment: Nice catch. It worked with 2038-01-01. This means the y2k bug will be January 20th 2038 :)

Comment: Exactly, 23 years remaining before enjoying this y2k v2 bug ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the column "time" since it's a keyword in MySql.

```
`time`
```

See this answer: [i can't use 'time' word in mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965687/i-cant-use-time-word-in-mysql-query)

Comment: This was actually a nice catch too

Comment: TIME is currently no [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.